# NOT a "localhost" socket networking example

Tags: java, sockets

You might have heard of [Bucky's Instant Messenger tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEcztLI84A4) using java socket networking. A quick summary is that he is creating a connection on between a client and server using the `127.0.0.1` IP address. Everything worked for me, but when I tried to change the code and place it on two separate computers (client and server) it just doesn't establish a connection. What am I doing wrong?

SERVER CODE

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Server extends JFrame{

private JTextField userTextField;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private ServerSocket server;
private Socket connection;

//constructor
public Server()
{

    super("My Instant Messenger");
    userTextField = new JTextField();
    userTextField.setEditable(false);

    userTextField.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
     {

        sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
        userTextField.setText("");

     }
    }
    );

    add(userTextField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    chatWindow = new JTextArea();
    add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow));
    setSize(300,150);
    setVisible(true);
}


//set up and run the server

public void startRunning(){
 try{

  server = new ServerSocket(6789,100);
  while(true)
  {
      try{

          waitForConnection();
          setupStreams();
          whileChatting();

      }catch(EOFException e){
       showMessage("\n Server ended the connection! ");  
      }finally{
       closeCrap();  
      }
  }

 }catch(IOException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 }

}

//wait for connection, then display connection information
private void waitForConnection() throws IOException{
    showMessage(" Waiting for someone to connect... \n");
    connection = server.accept();
    showMessage(" Now Connected to " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}

//get stream to send and receive data
private void setupStreams() throws IOException{

    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();

    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    showMessage("\n Streams are now setup! \n");

}

//during the chat coversation
private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    String message = "You are now connected!";
    sendMessage(message);
    ableToType(true);
    do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n " + message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            showMessage("\n idk wtf that user sent!");
        }
    }while(!message.equals("CLIENT - END"));
}

//close streams and sockets after you are done chating
private void closeCrap(){
    showMessage("\n Closing connection... \n");
    ableToType(false);
    try{

        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();

    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//send a message to client
private void sendMessage (String message){
    try{

        output.writeObject("SERVER -  " + message);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\nSERVER - " + message);

    }catch(IOException e){
        chatWindow.append("\n ERROR: DUDE I CANT SEND THAT MESSAGE!");
    }
}    

//update chatWindow
private void showMessage(final String text){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
    new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        chatWindow.append(text);
    }
    }
    );
}

//let the user type stuff into their box
private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
    new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        userTextField.setEditable(tof);
    }
    }
    );
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Server sally = new Server();
    sally.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    sally.startRunning();
}

}
```

CLIENT CODE

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Client extends JFrame{
private JTextField userTextField;
private JTextArea chatWindow;
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;
private String message = "";
private String serverIP;
private Socket connection;

//constructor
public Client(String host){

    super("Client");
    serverIP = host;
    userTextField = new JTextField();
    userTextField.setEditable(false);
    userTextField.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                sendMessage(event.getActionCommand());
                userTextField.setText("");
            }
        }
    );
    add(userTextField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    chatWindow = new JTextArea();
    add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setSize(300,150);
    setVisible(true);
}

//connect to server
public void startRunning(){
    try{
        connectToServer();
        setUpStreams();
        whileChatting();
    }catch(EOFException e){
        showMessage("\n Client terminated connection");
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
        closeCrap();
    }
}

//connect to server
private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
    showMessage("Attempting connection... \n");
    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP), 6789);
    showMessage("Connected to: " + connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}

//set up streams to send and receive messages
private void setUpStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
    showMessage("\n Dude your streams are now good to go! \n");
}

//while chating with server
private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    ableToType(true);
    do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n" + message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            showMessage("\n i dont know that object type");
        }
    }while(!message.equals("SERVER - END"));
}

//close the streams and sockets
private void closeCrap(){
    showMessage("\n closing crap down...");
    ableToType(false);
    try{
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//send messages to server
private void sendMessage(String message){
    try{
        output.writeObject("CLIENT - " + message);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\nCLIENT - " + message);
    }catch(IOException e){
        chatWindow.append("\n something messed up sending message host!");
    }
}

//update chatWindow
private void showMessage(final String message){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                chatWindow.append(message);
            }
        }
    );
}

//gives user permission to type crap into the text box
private void ableToType(final boolean tof){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
        new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                userTextField.setEditable(tof);
            }
        }
    );
}

public static void main (String[] args){
    Client charlie;
    charlie = new Client("127.0.0.1");
    charlie.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    charlie.startRunning();
}
}
```

Comment: I assume you figured out the two IP addresses of the 2 computers.
What port are you opening? Is there a firewall active? (can you show us your code?)

Comment: Details about the servers?  Other network hardware?  Errors binding the to socket?

Comment: @PhilW port is 6789, I also tried new ServerSocket(0), but it still doesn't connect

Comment: Do you have an exception? Could you add your code to the question?

Comment: Are the computers in a LAN?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis no they are not

Comment: @PhilW posted the code, thx for your help!

Comment: The thing you need to do is to first make sure that you can ping your server from your client before trying to run your program, then also make sure that the port your server is binding is not blocked by the firewall

Comment: @GeraldSv how do I ping the server from the client? is there code for that?

Comment: @tiffanyButterfly23 If you're on Windows, you can open CMD and execute `ping <address>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Java itself when running on a platform with IPv4 and v6.

Try binding your serverSocket to a IPv4 address either `"0.0.0.0"` which means all IPs available on this host or use the one you have in the client code (`192.168.x.x`)

Like this

```
server = new ServerSocket(6789, 100, InetAddress.getByName("0.0.0.0"));
```

Comment: what happens if I use my external IP address for the server? I imagine that's what I have to do to make this work on different computers. I tried doing so, but it doesn't work

Comment: I assume external IP would be your public WAN IP (internet). This depends on your network configuration: If you have a router/modem, the WAN-IP would be assigned to that device and your PC has a LAN IP (10.x.x.x or 192.168.x.x or something like that). You would need to use NAT (network address ("Port Forwarding") translation) for that.

Comment: I will look into that, but where does NAT(port forwarding) clash with socket networking in java? Cause it seems like every time I read other questions and answers, people never mention them together.

Comment: It doesn't really have to do with Java, it has to do with networking in general. You have to look at it in layers: telling Java to open a socket tells the OS (operating system) to open a socket on the network driver etc. And when you connect, it goes through the OS, the firewall, the router, modem etc. - So at any point of these steps, there could be a problem, which does not have with Java but with the network (or the operating system).
Since the outbound connection (PC to Internet) is usually working, only firewall & routing (NAT) configuration is left to configure for inbound communication